# Favorite tags not getting saved

Tags: support, bookmarks

Steps to reproduce:

1. On the home screen introduce a new favorite tag
2. Click on the Add button
3. Click on the newly added favorite tag
4. Go back in the browser window
5. Verify that the newly added favorite tag isn't there.

If, for instance, after adding the new favorite tag I click on the StackOverflow icon, I'll go once again to the home screen and the newly added tag will be there. Different behaviors for the same kind of action.

Comment: You can add an extra step "6. Press F5 and verify the newly added favorite tag is indeed there after all". Just browser caching at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply browser caching at work, and has nothing to do with our code.

Also of note:

1. Enter an answer on a question
2. Click Submit Answer
3. Go back in the browser window
4. Verify that the newly added answer isn't there

Comment: I thought of just that, but after clearing my cache the tag still wasn't there.

Comment: You can close the question now. Don't know what happened with my browser but even after pressing F5 I wasn't getting the tag I added. But now I can't reproduce it. Probably a bug in the browser and not in SO :) Sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 2):

By clicking "back", you haven't reloaded the page. I would also, for example, not expect new questions to appear. If I do this, then at step 4 *indeed* the tag that I added on-the-fly does not appear. But if I hit "refresh" it *does* appear. I've tried this a couple of times in a row; I *cannot* get it to misbehave, except what you would expect by caching.

If this really does recur, what browser etc are you using?